# How to externally influence JavaScript running in a page

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'd like to be able to make the JavaScript I've got in a web page behave differently by doing something or setting something externally. So there'll be logic checking if(something) execute functionality one, else execute functionality two. I can think of three ways of doing this, but I don't like any of them enough to choose it. At least not unless I can see if there's another blindingly obvious way of doing it that's somehow escaping me at the moment.

1. Add a harmless query string to the URL (e.g. ?choose_functionality_one=true) and my logic can simply look in the page URL. The reason I don't like this is the case where my code is running inside a cross-domain iframe and I can't even access the page's URL (only the iframe's URL). Yes I could pass the query string to the iframe, but only if I have control over the parent page, and I don't.
2. Create a cookie in the domain of the page, and my logic can simply look for it in document.cookie. This could be done with a bookmarklet easily enough, and wouldn't suffer from the cross-domain problem, because I simply open a window/tab to the domain where my code is running and run the bookmarklet in that context. This is my front-runner choice at the moment.
3. Add something to the browser's useragent string and look for that in my logic. Pretty easy on Firefox via about:config, but is less easy with the other browsers, and downright difficult on the Mac. Also, on some browsers, once you've set a custom value, you lose the ability to have the UA get auto-updated when you get a browser update. Your UA's version info is stuck in time to where it was when you first custom'ed it.

Can anyone think of another way that via email/IM/phone I can say to someone "do this" and they'll see the page behave differently for troubleshooting purposes. For the general population who haven't done that though, it's running completely normally.

Comment: I would recommend a global `enableDebug` method you can call. Just ask the user to open the command line and type `enableDebug()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It falls down with the fact that all the code I want to influence can be in an iframe in another domain, and not accessible to code executed in the address bar (which is what I assume you meant by command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option seems to be to make a debug page on your site that will let the user turn the "debug" cookie on/off and then queue your regular site code off the existence of the cookie.  I'd suggest making the debug cookie expire in a fairly short amount of time so people don't inadvertently leave it on.

This option has the advantages you are interested in (no user agent modification, works on all platforms, works with iframes) and I can see no disadvantages except that it wouldn't work if someone had cookies off, though a lot of the web won't work without cookies these days so that seems like something you could live with.

In addition, it's also the simplest for your users to use.  You can just direct them to the right page on your site and all they have to do is click the desired button to turn it on or off.  You can make the page very self explanatory which is certainly much easier than any of the other options.

OK, if you only control code and no HTML, then you could do either implement a keyboard shortcut key that would enable the debug mode by setting the cookie.  The instructions could be something like this: put the keyboard focus in X and then press Ctrl-D.

Or, you could implement some special type of click (like a Ctrl-click on some object or in some page corner).  In this case the instructions could be something like: Hold down the Ctrl-key and click on object X on the page.

Your JS code could implement either of those shortcuts.  You could even put up a prompt (all with dynamically created HTML objects) when the special key/click was engaged to confirm turning the debug mode on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there is no "your site". The code I want to influence can be loaded (JS file) into the top page, or it can be loaded in a cross-domain iframe. I'm thinking now that my bookmarklet is looking like the best option still. It just needs to be run from whatever domain the code is being loaded into, which might involve opening a separate window/tab, going to the root of that domain and running the bookmarklet there, then come back to the original page and refresh and should be good to go. Or if the code is loaded in the top page, run the bookmarklet there.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  You say right in your question: "JavaScript I've got in a web page".  The way most people would interpret that is that there is a web site that has your code in it and you control the contents of that code.  And now you're telling me that you can't add a new page to that site?  Perhaps if you described the whole context of what you're trying to do rather than pushing us down the solution path you're looking at, we could better help.

Comment: There's always some important point missing from every question, in this case it was that I don't control the page, it's just my code that's included into it. If you're that upset about my question not being perfect, I'll be happy to mark your suggestion as the answer. All I can offer in my defence is that I tried my best.

Comment: OK, I added one more idea to my answer.  Since you only control code, I'm not sure what else to offer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm considering whether I can make that keyboard approach work. Timing-wise, they'd have to hit the key at just the right time during page load. If they hit the key before my JS was loaded, then my code isn't there to see it. If they hit it after my JS has loaded, it's too late because my code has already made it's choices. It's not like it's sitting there running and I can asynchronously tell it to work in debug mode. It's a choice it makes as it's initializing (taking all external factors into consideration). Perhaps a key permanently held down though, that could work.

Comment: I think you're looking at this too narrowly.  The point of the debug on/off switch is to set the switch for future visits, not necessarily to have enacted the switch for the very page load that is live.  So, you could have your code hook some object on the page for keystrokes.  After the page was loaded, the user could press the key to turn on the debug mode.  They could then hit refresh and the debug mode would be on when the page was loaded and it would be on for all future page loads.  This makes a lot more sense to me than trying to "catch" a keystroke while your code is initializing.

Comment: You are of course completely correct. That does resolve my remaining issue :-) Cheeeeeers !!!